# Remover em massa ou a partir de um grupo

Tags: php, google-api

Estou utilizando a Google People API e preciso fazer uma operação de remoção (delete) em massa. Dei uma olhada na documentação deles, mas não encontrei nenhuma forma de deletar todos os contatos da agenda ou de um determinado grupo (tipo mandar um batch, por exemplo).

Eu vi que havia uma forma de remover todos os contatos de um determinado grupo quando apagasse o próprio grupo. Implementei isso, mas não funcionou. Na verdade, não funcionou nem no próprio [dashboard da google](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups/delete?authuser=2). Entretanto, no gerenciador de contatos deles funciona.

Tentei inspecionar as requests, mas não deu muito certo também. Minha implementação está assim:

```
/**
* Delete a group
* @param $resourceName //Group resource name
* @param $deleteContacts //Verify if it should delete the members
* @return Object
*/
public function deleteGroup($resourceName, $deleteContacts = false) {
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/'.$resourceName.'?deleteContacts='.($deleteContacts ? 'true' : 'false'));        
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $this->access_token));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    return $response;
}
```

Alguém tem ideia do que eu poderia fazer?